# bootstrap & javascript: sequence of commands

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

The following javascript code executes in the following order:
 1. shows label,
 2. shows alert,
 3. shows modal;

but the sequence of the commands in the code is different(see code).

In debug mode execution goes in normal order.

What is happening here?

How to get normal order in runtime?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="file" onchange="openFile(event)"/>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">header</div>
                <div class="modal-body">body</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label id="label" style="display:none;">this is label</label>

    <script>
        openFile = function (event) {
            $('#label')[0].style.display = 'block';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            alert('alert');
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback of model to run something after model is loaded.

```
openFile = function (event) {
            $('#label')[0].style.display = 'block';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
                 alert('alert');
            })
        }
```

If Bootstrap 3

```
    openFile = function (event) {
            $('#label')[0].style.display = 'block';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
                 alert('alert');
            })

        }
```

Comment: What if instead of alert there is another function which needs parameter event?

Comment: @Qvatra, 'event' variable is accessible from inner callback function.
for Ex : alert(event);

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) if you want to make something happen in an explicit order, since jQuery often kicks events asynchrounusly. With deferred objects you can wait for a function to finish, and then define a callback which will be kicked after the said function is done executing.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap `.modal()` mechanism (like most of the Bootstrap architecture) drives layout changes via events. To show a modal dialog, the code generates a new Event object and triggers it. That's handled asynchronously by the browser, in that the event handler is invoked in a separate (subsequent) event loop.

Here's the first bit of the modal "show" code in the current github master branch:

```
  Modal.prototype.show = function (_relatedTarget) {
    var that = this
    var e = $.Event('show.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

    this.$element.trigger(e)
```

The handler for that "show.bs.modal" event just adds a class to the `<div>` involved.